# Cycling through JavaScript Objects in a JSON

Tags: javascript, json, object

I'm requesting data from a website via POST request and already isolated the needed data/key pair with setting

```
relevant_listings = data["listings"];
```

If I print the listings to the console I get a bunch of objects with a lot of different properties and values:

```
Object {350503275519564011: Object, 359510012249522033: Object, 358384527390382582: Object, 826758911669189345: Object, 827884358724814556: Object…}
```

I know how I do access the properties from the very first object that is returned:

```
for (var key in relevant_listings) {
        console.log(relevant_listings[key]["property1"]);
```

However I can't find a way to cycle through the different objects and get the property1 from the second object for example.

Would you be so kind to help me out with the correct syntax/way to approach this?

Kind regards,

Comment: what keys do the Objects have?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get random json object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31299996/get-random-json-object)

Comment: Try using lodash or underscore for this, they abstract things like these in cross-browser ways.

Comment: Well, if you have an array of objects, can't you just loop through it and then loop through properties in a nested `for`? I don't understand what's the problem/question.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a single `for` loop to cycle though your parent object you won't be able to access the child object's properties. You can, among many strategies, use nested for loops. For instance,

```
var data = {
    obj1: {
        dog: "retriever",
        name: "bob"
    },
    obj2: {
        dog: "poodle",
        name: "jim"
    }
};

for (var p in data) {
    console.log(p) //"obj1", "obj2"
    console.log(data[p]) //this doesn't access the child properties of the nested object

    //check if the property of your parent object is a nested object
    if (typeof data[p] === "object") {

        /**
         * another way to write this nested loop is
         * var nestedObject = data[p];
         * for (var q in nestedObject) { //etc.... }
         */

        for (var q in data[p]) {
            console.log(data[p][q]) //"retriever", "bob", "poodle", "jim"
        }
    }
}
```